# Prove or disprove that the given group is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

Let $K=K_1 \cup K_2 \cup \dots \cup K_n$ be a finite union of tori in 3-space (each $K_i$, $i=1,2,\dots, n$ is a torus). For $i=1,2,\dots, n$, let $a_i$ be the meridian and let $b_i$ be the longitude  of $K_i$. Define the group $G$ that is generated by the set
$ X=\{(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2),\dots,(a_n,b_n)\} $
The element of $X$ (generator of $G$) is the pair $(a_i,b_i)$ $i=1,2,\dots,n$, that is the meridian longitude pair. My question is: Is $G$ abelian?

Comment: What are the operation of your group? Is it freely generated by $X$? Are we dealing with some algebraic invariant of $K$? It's somewhat unclear exactly what $G$ actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get is not an abelian group but the free product of $n$ free Abelian groups of rank 2. Of course I assume that all the loops are deformed to be based at the same point.